# Angular can't bind to 'product' since it isn't a known property of 'app-products-card'

Tags: angular

I did Import to BrowserModule and to ReactiveFormsModule, and still getting this bind error.

I am using the state service to get the prudcts array from the server..

**This is the home component**

```
<div class="product-container" *ngFor="let product of stateService.products| category:stateService.categoryId">
<app-products-card  [product]="product"></app-products-card>
</div>
```

**This is from the home.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  products: IProducts[] = []

  constructor(
    public stateService: StateService,
    public productServices: ProductService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,

  ) { }
```

**This is the product component**

```
<div class="card productsCard" style="width: 18rem">
  <img
    [src]="product.image"
    alt="{{ product.productName }}"
    width="250px"
    class="card-img-top"
    style="cursor: pointer"
  />
  
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.productName | titlecase }}</h5>
    <p class="card-text"> {{ product.price }}</p>
    <a *ngIf="stateService.isLoggedIn && !isAddToCartBtnClicked"  href="#" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</a>
    <div *ngIf="isAddToCartBtnClicked">
      Amount: <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="amount"/>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The Imports:**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    TableModule,
  ],
  
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: can you provide the component ts file, that might help

Comment: Maybe this happen because the service is private and you are accessing it from the template, why you are not puting the stateService.products in a variable/property,

Comment: is the product is an @input in app-products-card component ?

Comment: I add a segment from the home.ts , and what do you mean if the product is an @input ?

Comment: This is the official docs https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs and this is an example
https://guide-angular.wishtack.io/angular/interaction-entre-composants/input

Comment: @BarJa please show us the typescript of your product component. If you don't have any, you have to learn the basics of angular components

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add @Input() in your AppProductsCardComponent

```
export class AppProductsCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product: IProducts; //Add @Input()

  constructor(
    public stateService: StateService,
    public productServices: ProductService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,

  ) { }
```

Comment: Yep , that was it,  I added @Input to my AppProductsCardComponent, and it was fixed.  Thanks A lot!

Comment: Same, just needed the @Input()

Answer (score 0):

Add into product.component.ts
@Input() product;
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in `AppProductCardComponent`, you missed to add product as an `Input` field. With Angular, you can only pass value to a component if you have added Input() field to that component which needs a value to be passed from Parent component.

Like below:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-demo-comp',
   template: '<div>{{msg}}</div>
})
class DemoComponent {
    @Input() msg: string;
}
```

This is how you can use it:  `<app-demo-comp [msg]="'demo'"></app-demo-comp>`